# What responses will show up in an OP's inbox?

Tags: support, comments, notifications, comment-replies

In some cases I would like to make sure that an OP is notified of a comment I make (because, say, the comment is in some way a request for more information).

I expect that if I comment directly on their question, they will be notified (tell me if I'm wrong).

But I don't think that a comment made on an answer to their question will trigger a notification.  At least not based on my experience as an OP.

So if they comment on an answer I've made to their question, and I want to respond to their comment with a comment, is there any guarantee that they will be notified of my comment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If they commented on your answer and you include `@their-user-name` in your comment, they will be notified. You cannot notify OP this way if he didn't comment your answer. See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Otherwise, they will only be notified if you comment on one of their posts.

Comment: Thanks for the link, previously I wasn't sure whether the @user was informal or triggered a notify.

Comment: @brainjam: You should be notified of this comment.

Comment: yes, I got notified.

Comment: what if @brainjam was notified just because he already commented on this post?