# Always notify the OP when @OP's-user-name is mentioned in comments

Tags: feature-request, comment-replies

As I already suggested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52368/does-op-also-notify-the-op/52374#52374), it would be nice if the OP is also notified of comments on answers when *@OP's-user-name* is used, even if the OP isn't a participator in a comment discussion on that answer, yet.

This way, I can e.g. make an (IMHO) important comment on an answer *and* notify the OP.

Comment: If there's a collision (someone with the same name as the OP already commented in the comment thread), who should get the notification?

Comment: @TheCat Collisions are already possible and handled as the most recent. I think the implied question is "Who gets priority if the OP isn't in the comment thread?": If Jon Skeet asked a question, Jonathan Sampson posted an answer, Jon B edited the answer, and Jon Seigel made a comment, who gets notified if you follow Jon Seigel with @Jon?

Comment: I believe Jon S would be notified.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is worthwhile. Today on English.SE, I asked a question, got some answers, and someone [tried to ping me](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204619/how-can-i-refer-to-people-who-live-in-the-other-half-of-a-duplex#comment432909_204622) on an answer. I only noticed it because I actually came back to look at it again.

Comment: Well, if the comment is important enough the user can also post comment under the question itself, e.g. "see my comment on the answer".

Comment: I've experienced this as well (IIRC, it was also on English, but I'm not 100% sure).

Comment: @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard Only if you know that you need to do that. For years(!) I've been "pinging" the _asker_ by commenting on my answer (where the comment is in context), thinking this was "working" (there was nothing to suggest that it wasn't). Having to comment on the question itself in order to "ping" the _asker_ is not intuitive and "messy" as it promotes entirely out-of-context comments.

Answer (score 3):

If it's that important *and* the OP hasn't participated in that answer yet *and* you think the OP won't notice it when reading answers later (but if he doesn't care that much...), then you should comment on the answer and the question.  Delete one of those comments later.  All three of these conditions combined should be really rare.

I only want to check *one* place to see who will match, especially on questions with several answers (say 7-9).  Not the current question and somewhere else, even if that is only the OP's name.  You'd have to determine a sort order, and it's just not worth the complication.  Keep it simple.  If you must ping them, you know how to do it: comment on the question.

**Stack Exchange isn't instant messaging**, even if it's important we can [reply](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/) sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Being able to `@<asker>` (and "ping" the question asker) in comments to answers where the *asker* has not yet participated is generally *expected* behaviour. There is nothing to suggest (at the time of posting) that this does not have the desired effect. As [@Catija has stated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362695/is-the-question-asker-notified-of-updates-to-answers-without-explicitly-followi/362696?noredirect=1#comment1210567_362696):

> a relatively common point of confusion about our reply system.

In my experience, "relatively common" is an understatement. I see many instances of this "expected" behaviour in the *wild*. I myself thought it worked this way for years(!) before finding out only recently that this does not have the desired result (consequently many many comments I've posted have quite possibly been in vain).

Typical/common use cases where this is "necessary":

- You need to notify the *asker* of an important update to your own answer. This might be after the answer has already been accepted (when the user is less likely to naturally revisit the question).
- You need to notify the *asker* because of inaccuracies in an accepted answer.

Having to "ping" the *asker* by commenting on the question itself is very counter intuitive. It is also "messy" and promotes out-of-context comments on the question. (Comments on the question are intended to seek clarification about the question.)

Comment: Well, a decent feature request would be to have the asker automatically follow the answer when they upvote it or post a comment under that answer. Then they'll indeed get notified when any comment is posted under that answer.