# Responding to comments from the OP

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette

So sometimes I answer a question and the OP responds in comments asking for further clarification. When I update the answer, I'd like to notify the OP that I've changed my answer.

I like to respond in the body of the ANSWER because of the formatting options and it gives users that find the question later the details right away.

But this doesn't seem to notify the author. I find myself posting stubby comments:

`@OP: I've updated my answer for you.`

Or something to this effect.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52376/always-notify-the-op-when-ops-user-name-is-mentioned-in-comments) regarding allowing @ notifications to work against the OP when used in answers regardless of the OP's participation.

However, editing your answer automatically notifies the OP in the first place. So you don't need to make an update comment manually. If you want to add yet more words, though, comment replies should work as long as the OP has actually posted a comment on your answer. Doublecheck that you're following the [guidelines in the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

If the OP hasn't commented, I suggest commenting on the question itself with a short "I've updated my answer" followed by the aforementioned 'yet more words'.