# Add auto-completion for username in comments when typing @

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-replies, autocomplete

It would be nice that username auto-completion  in comments starts when the user type `@` (vs `@` + first letter of the name of the intended user

[image]

)

I am aware of the StackApp [Reply links on comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2051/reply-links-on-comments).

Comment: Nice idea, surprised nobody suggested it before. Naturally, the first name that will appear is the last person who pinged you.

Comment: It's too bad that the two downvoters didn't share what could be a downside of this feature.

Comment: Can't really know, from own experience starting to wonder about this is pointless. But as long as the net score is positive, all is good - in a sense.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Wouldn't it be nice to reduce the number of keystrokes? My use case is as follows: I use the computer hands-free and in order to trigger the auto-completion I need to dictate both the  `@` character as well as the first character of the username (then I either dictate `tab` or choose the intended username using a hands-free pointing device). Dictating a character is a costly operation (~ 1 second), and as a result adding the `@ShadowWizard` almost takes as much time as dictating the rest of a short comment.

Comment: No need to convince me, I already upvoted. :)

Comment: This works, unfortunatelly except for the OP's name, [which is possible to notify as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48729/166308). I [added a feature request for that :-)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331670/166308) BTW, shouldn't this be marked as [tag:status-completed]?

Comment: @Tomas not completed yet as still nothing appeared after typing `@`.

Answer (score 2):

We have an existing feature to autocomplete the name in comment box. It works with <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

#### For ex:

<kbd>@</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> = **ShadowWizard**

[image: comment shortcut]

Comment: Thanks, I use the keyboard sparingly and would prefer the auto completion to start when I type `@` :-)